# HTTP Error 500.19 IIS .net core 2.1 with error code 0x80070005

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core, .net-core, iis-10

I'm trying to host a asp.net core 2.1 website using IIS. But I keep getting this error while I have installed the .net core 2.1 hosting pack and link rewrite package:

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be
>   accessed because the related configuration data for the page is
>   invalid.
>
> Detailed Error Information:
>
> Module       IIS Web Core
>
> Notification Unknown
>
> Handler      Not yet determined
>
> Error Code       0x80070005 Config
>   Error    Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions
>
> Config File      \?\C:\Users\USER\source\repos\Frontis.Forecast\Frontis.Forecast\Frontis.Forecast.Web\bin\Release\PublishOutput\web.config

Comment: Maybe the IIS_User (or the one impersonates the server) does not have permission to access that folder?

Comment: @PepitoSh Where would that be? anything under C that not in the users folder?

Comment: CodeCaster gave the correct answer. Put you publish output (or copy) to a folder that IIS has access to. For example C:\inetpub\wwwroot or equivalent, or drive d:.

Comment: It is permission issue. You can try to give full permission to your folder.

Comment: @Mark - Danger!

Comment: @PepitoSh Danger???

Comment: @PepitoSh Danger? Could you please explain clearly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions

You're hosting the site from your user profile. The user running the application pool in IIS doesn't have permissions to read from your profile.

Deploy the site to a folder that the IIS app pool user has permissions to.